# Доступ к данным Google Play Console через API

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

В `Google Play Console` (Консоль разработчика приложений для Play Market) можно узнать:

1. Точное количество установок приложения
2. Количество оценок.
3. Средний балл приложения
4. Количество оценок.
5. Рабочую версию приложения

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы хотел каким-либо образом вывести эти данные на свой сайт, но никаких `API` найти не удалось, либо я плохо строю поисковые запросы...

Существует ли у Google открытый `API` для доступа к этим данным?

Comment: похоже тебе нужно [вот это](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started)